# TypeScript iterating over object and creating a new one

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two objects of the same interface.

```
interface SizeFilter {
  key: string | undefined
}

const defaultFilter = {
    key: undefined,
} as SizeFilter;
```

I have a function which basically checks if there is a key set in a state and accordingly get filter options:

```
const { filters } = useSelector(({ sizeCurves }) => sizeCurves);


// Get FilterOptions for filtering on the page.
const getSelectedFilters = () => {
    const pageFilter = defaultFilter;
    // TODO: add an Object loop to check all properties and define value.
    pageFilter.sizeCurveKey = filters.sizeCurveKey ?? undefined ;
    return pageFilter;
};
```

I have to decide whether I should take a filter value from the filters or from a default filter. And for that, I am setting `pageFilter` in the `getSelectedFilters` function.

When I try to iterate over `defaultFilter` using `Object.Keys().map`,

```
Object.keys(defaultFilter).map(key =>{
             const pageFilter[item] = (defaultFilter[ key ])? defaultFilter[ key ] : undefined;
        });
```

My editor throws warning on `defaultFilter[ key ]`

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'SizeFilter'.   No index
> signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
> 'SizeFilter'.

I am not sure how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is to prevent runtime errors that come from indexing an object by unknown keys. To prevent that you need to check first if the key is valid for defaultFilter. You can achieve this with a small helper function:

```
function hasKey<O>(obj: O, key: keyof any): key is keyof O { return key in obj }
```

You can use the function like this afterwards:

```
    if (hasKey(defaultFilter, key)) { 
       defaultFilter[key] 
    }
```